# A remark on triangulated categories and localizations in Kashiwara & Schapira's *Sheaves on Manifolds*

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, triangulated-categories

I'm having a little difficulty understanding the following remark in Kashiwara & Schapira's *Sheaves on Manifolds*:

[image: remark]

Since the term "null system" doesn't appear to be very common, here is the definition, along with its main application:

[image: null system]

The notation $\mathcal{C}/\mathcal{N}$ in the remark stands for the localization of $\mathcal{C}$ at $S(\mathcal{N}).$ The functor $Q$ is the canonical functor sending a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ to the roof $X \xleftarrow{1} X \xrightarrow{f} Y.$

Now, I'm fine with one direction. Namely, it's clear enough that if there exists $Y$ such that $X \oplus Y \in \mathcal{N},$ then $Q(X) \cong 0,$ for the triangulated category and null system axioms show that $X \oplus Y$ being in $\mathcal{N}$ is equivalent to the zero morphism $X \oplus Y \rightarrow 0$ being in $S(\mathcal{N}).$ Hence $0 \leftarrow X \oplus Y \rightarrow X$ is a roof in $\mathcal{C}/\mathcal{N},$ so that the diagram

[image: diagram]

shows that $X$ is isomorphic to $0$ in the localization (here $i,$ resp. $p,$ is the canonical inclusion, resp. projection).

The other direction is still unclear to me. We have a diagram of roofs

[image],

where $Z \in \mathcal{N}$ and $f \circ g = 1.$ I have tried to show that $Z \cong X \oplus X[1],$ but I don't even think it is true.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The morphism $g\colon X \to Z$ sits in a distinguished triangle$\require{AMScd}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$
$$
\begin{CD}
X @>g>> Z @>g'>> Y @>\delta>> X[1]
\end{CD}
$$
The relation $fg = 1_X$ implies that $g$ is monic. Since the composition of consecutive maps in a distinguished triangle is zero, $g \circ (\delta[-1]) = 0$, and this implies that $\delta[-1] = 0$. Therefore $\delta = 0$.

Now observe that we have a morphism of distinguished triangles
\begin{CD}
X  @>g>> Z @>g'>> Y @>0>> X[1]\cr
@VV{1_{X}}V @VV{[f \; g']^t}V @VV{1_{Y}}V @VV1_{X[1]}V \cr
X  @>[1_X \; 0]^t>> X \oplus Y @>[0\;1_Y]>> Y @>0>> X[1]
\end{CD}
and we deduce from the five lemma for triangulated categories that $[f \; g']^t\colon Z \to X \oplus Y$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: This shows that there is $Y$ such that $X \oplus Y \in \mathcal{N}$. I think I can leave the fact that this is equivalent to $X \oplus X[1] \in \mathcal{N}$ to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, Martin. For the last non-trivial part of the question, is this reasoning correct? We have a distinguished triangle $0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow X \rightarrow 0,$ where the middle arrow is the identity. Then since the direct sum of distinguished triangles is distinguished, from $X \oplus Y \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X[1] \rightarrow X[1] \oplus Y[1]$ we get the distinguished triangle $X \oplus Y \rightarrow X \oplus Y \rightarrow X \oplus X[1] \rightarrow X[1] \oplus Y[1]$. Since $X \oplus Y \in \mathcal{N},$ we have $X \oplus X[1] \in \mathcal{N}.$

Comment: @AlexP. Yes, that's correct. Alternatively, you can go through the implication you proved in your question and deduce that $X, Y \in \mathcal{N}$, so $X,X[1] \in \mathcal{N}$ by (N2). Then add the two distinguished triangles $0 \to X \to X \to 0$ and $0 \to 0 \to X[1] \to X[1]$ and apply (N3).

Comment: By the way: it is a good exercise to show that in a distinguished triangle $\delta = 0$ is equivalent to $g$ monic and this implies that $Z \cong X \oplus Y$. To see this, apply the homological functor $\operatorname{Hom}({-},X)$ to see that there must be a left inverse $f$ for $g$ and apply the five lemma as above. ("All monics in a triangulated category split").

Comment: I don't understand how we can deduce that $X,Y \in \mathcal{N}.$ Are you saying that $Q(X) \cong 0$ is *equivalent* to $X \in \mathcal{N},$ or that $X,Y \in \mathcal{N} \iff X \oplus Y \in \mathcal{N}?$ I didn't think either was true.

Comment: @AlexP. Oops, you're right, sorry. I was silently working under the assumption that a null system also satisfies this condition, but according to K-S's assumptions this need not be the case.

Comment: @AlexP. A triangulated subcategory is *thick* if it is closed under taking direct summands (your second condition). The kernel of a triangle functor is always  thick. If you localize a triangulated category at a null system $\mathcal{N}$ in the sense of K-S, the kernel of the localization functor $Q \colon \mathcal{T} \to \mathcal{T/N}$ will be the *thick closure* of $\mathcal{N}$, i.e., the objects $X$ for which there is $Y$ such that $X \oplus Y \in \mathcal{N}$. This is basically the content of remark 1.6.11.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight, Martin. It's hard to express how clearer this is to me now!